# Make a click to call addon for a WPF application

Tags: wpf, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a WPF calling application and i want to create click to call add ons for IE, Firefox, Chrome and MS Excel. So that every number on a web page is called using my application. 
Basically what i am looking for is how to make an click to call add on for my application.

Help appreciated greatly !

Comment: So you want to make numbers in a webpage clickable? On click it will open in this application?

Comment: Yes, and if the user is logged in then the number should be copied in the number field and the user can click the dial button to make a call.

Comment: Ok can you post a screenshot and other details of how the app is loaded into the browser. (Like for firefox use DOM Inspector addon and Element Inspector and then shift+right click on your application and then post screenshot of dom tree) this will tell us how to acess it.